# When should generatePom for maven deploy-file be set to false?

Tags: java, maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I am calling deploy-file like this to load some JARs into my corporate repository:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file \
  -Dfile=lib/SomeLib.jar \
  -DrepositoryId=mycompany-central \
  -Durl=http://myserver/artifactory/libs-release-local -DgeneratePom=false \
  -DgroupId=com.some.lib \
  -DartifactId=SomeLib \
  -Dversion=1.2.5.3
```

I set `generatePom` to `false` under the assumption that I want to generate or alter as little as possible. The libraries I am loading happened to be built using maven and also contain a POM under `META-INF`.

**Question**: Under what conditions, in general, should `generatePom` be set to `false`? Should `generatePom` be set to `false` in my case?

Comment: If you provide a pom withit you can set generatePom to false. If they already have been built with Maven why manually uploading them to your repository ? Furthermore if you a pom file extract it from the jar and use that for your deployment...

Comment: It was built by maven by another company 2 years ago. I don't have the source code. Is there any difference between a generated pom and using the pom extracted from the JAR?

Comment: Also, if I use the pom from the JAR will deploy-file just get the artifact name, groupId, and version from the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pom.xml` file is required for transitive dependencies. Transitive dependencies are dependencies defined in the `dependencies` section, if any, of the `.pom` file available as part of a deployed artefact.

The `.pom` file is essentially a copy of the original `pom.xml` file, renamed to reflect the library name (i.e. `artifactId-version.jar`, then `artifactId-version.pom`).

When resolving a dependency, maven will also check its `.pom` file and as such get information about its dependencies (which become transitive dependencies then) and build (and fetch) the required dependencies graph for it (that is, re-iterate the same process for each and every declared dependency).

From official [Maven - Introduction to the dependency mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

> This feature is facilitated by reading the **project files** of your dependencies from the remote repositories specified. In general, all dependencies of those projects are used in your project, as are any that the project inherits from its parents, or from its dependencies, and so on.

Note: bold is mine. *project files* are normally the `pom.xml` files, renamed into `*.pom` files once related artifacts are uploaded to a Maven repository (or installed into the local Maven cache).

Using `-DgeneratePom=false`, we should hence pass a `pom.xml` file via the [`pomFile`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html#pomFile) option, otherwise (setting `generatePom` to `true`) a new one would be [automatically generated](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#generatePom)

> Generate a minimal POM for the artifact if none is supplied via the parameter `pomFile`. Defaults to `true` if there is no existing POM in the local repository yet.

The autogenerated `.pom` file will be almost empty (Maven coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version) but no `dependencies` section in it), hence Maven will treat this artefact as library with no transitive dependencies: it cannot find any, it cannot guess neither.

That would still be fine if actually no transitive dependencies were required. Otherwise, compilation (or runtime) errors would occur when using is as a dependency in another Maven project. If instead the artefact is deployed into a build-store, then transitive dependencies become less crucial and an automatically generated pom can still be fine.

---

From your comments:

> Is there any difference between a generated pom and using the pom extracted from the JAR?

As explained above, there are big differences between an automatically generated one and the original `pom.xml` file. But this difference is essentially only important if the target artifact will then be used as a maven dependency by another project. The `pom.xml` file stored under `META-INF` is normally a copy of the original one.

> Also, if I use the pom from the JAR will deploy-file just get the artifact name, groupId, and version from the file?

Yes, as specified by [official documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html):

> `groupId`: GroupId of the artifact to be deployed. Retrieved from POM file if specified.
>   `artifactId`: ArtifactId of the artifact to be deployed. Retrieved from POM file if specified.
>   `version`: Version of the artifact to be deployed. Retrieved from POM file if specified.

And also also specified by [the official example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-customed-pom.html)

> Note that the groupId, artifactId, version and packaging informations are automatically retrieved from the given pom.